# Book class and footnotes in the chapters' title

Tags: footnotes

I'm writing a thesis using the `book` article class. Some of the Chapters in my thesis are actually papers, and I would like to add a footnote in the title of these chapters to thank the co-authors.
This is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1 \footnotemark}\footnotetext{the note}
\end{document}
```

However, this code produces an error, `\@chapter doesn't match its definition`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `\protect\footnotemark`, which will stop the `\footnotemark` from expanding inside the definition for the chapter heading (which is what's causing the trouble).

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! Do you also know how to change the symbol of the titles' footmarks in such a way that they are different from the other footnote marks in the thesis? For example, do you know how to use a dagger, or a star, as marks for the section titles' footnotes and Arabic numbers for the marks of the other footnotes in the text?

Comment: Take a look at the `manyfoot` package. That might be able to create something that works (by defining a new footnote style which you then use in chapter headers): https://ctan.org/pkg/manyfoot?lang=en

Comment: To switch to symbols as footnote markers use `\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}` and to switch back to the normal Arabic numerals use `\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}`

Answer (score 3):

Note that the contents and header use the optional "short title" instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter[Short Title]{Chapter 1 \footnotemark}\footnotetext{the note}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```